# Running apt-get install updated unrelated packages and is causing issues

Tags: apt, kernel, bootloader

I recently ran `apt-get install unzip` on an Ubuntu server, for some reason it started updating almost every package on the system - apache, php, git, mysql, numerous libraries and more. Eventually it failed when trying to add a new kernel image:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-54-generic
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

There are loads of kernels installed. `uname -r` currently returns `3.5.0-36-generic` but there are about 10 newer kernels listed than that.

So my questions:

1. normal advice to clear `/boot` partition is to delete older kernels no longer used - can you delete newer kernels too? It's a remote server so if the bootloader breaks that's a real problem.
2. why did `apt-get install unzip` update so many unrelated packages?

Answer (score 1):

The "not enough space on boot" thing is an independent issue, which seems to be a constant problem for people who have disc encryption on. It seems to have been reported as a bug report for a year now but is still not fixed for some reason. You can fix it with

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

in the console -- this looks for which kernel packages you've got installed and then purges them all apart from the one you're currently running.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can possibily delete every kernel but the one you are using (cf., `uname -r`). You can maybe leave another one to be sure, but you certainly do not
   need 10.
2. I guess you have had some unconfigured packages the last time you ran `apt-get`/`dpkg`.